# What is the point of using compute() in sparklyr?

Tags: r, sparklyr

In the `sparklyr` tutorial I'm following it says I can use `compute()` to store the results of the preceding `dplyr` statement into a new spark data frame.

The code in 'code 1' creates a new spark data frame called "NewSparkDataframe" and a `spark_tbl` is created which I assigned to "NewTbl". I can view the spark data frame using `src_tbls()`. This is all as expected.

If I instead run 'code 2' without using `compute()` it still creates a `spark_tbl` which I again assign to "NewTbl". This time though I'm unable to view the new spark data frame in spark using `src_tbls()`.

I'm wondering how "NewTbl" is able to run the `spark_tbl` in code 2 if there's apparently no "NewSparkDataframe" in spark?

Also what is the point in using `compute()` if I can still access the same newly created `spark_tbl` with "NewTbl"?

code 1:

```
NewTbl <- mySparkTbl %>%
        some dplyr statements %>%
        compute("NewSparkDataframe")
src_tbls(spark_conn)
"NewSparkDataframe"
```

code 2:

```
NewTbl <- mySparkTbl %>%
        some dplyr statements
src_tbls(spark_conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses lazy evaluation, which means that you're not really storing or creating a table in the second case. When you call NewTbl in case 2, you evaluate it every time you call `NewTbl`.

What compute does is force the evaluation up front and store it in your session. This is great when you have to reuse a table often.